# plot lines using datetime strings in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, timestamp

I have a table text file like

```
id      t1                          t2
A01     2018-09-01T13:00:35.340000Z 2019-05-10T04:19:37.670000Z
A01     2019-02-04T13:45:05.540000Z 2020-05-30T04:00:00.670000Z
A02     2018-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z 2020-01-30T04:18:54.160000Z
B01     2017-04-01T10:10:01.229299Z 2017-06-11T23:59:59.969900Z
B01     2017-07-20T10:00:46.621871Z 2019-05-30T04:19:47.870500Z
......
```

Each `id` can have multiple rows indicating the available time periods.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.from_csv(file, sep='\s+')
```

I'm trying to plot the time availabilities of each id as horizontal lines.

Pseudocode:

```py
ids = list(set(df.id))

for i, id in enumerate(ids):
    for r in df[df.id==id].iterrows():
        plt.plot(r[['t1','t2']].values, [i,i])

set_yticks(range(len(ids)))
set_yticklabel(ids)
```

It would be sth like

[image: availability as lines]
and the yticklabels along with the lines are named after the `id`s.

Comment: `2020-02-30T04:18:54.160000Z` is an invalid datetime. How do you expect to handle invalid data?

Comment: @HenryEcker hahaha... I didn't notice. that's just for demonstration purpose

Comment: You might want to parse the strings to datetime before plotting, see [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a decent answer using `plt.yticks`.

```
ids = list(set(df.id))
id_dict = {ids[i] : i for i in range(len(ids))}
for i_row in range(len(df)):
    t1 = df.iloc[i_row,:].t1
    t2 = df.iloc[i_row,:].t2
    plot_row = id_dict[df.iloc[i_row,:].id]
    plt.plot([t1,t2], [plot_row, plot_row])

plt.yticks(ticks=list(id_dict.values()), labels=list(id_dict.keys()))
```

[image: resulting plot]

edit: (to clarify, I mocked up my own data, its not the table you posted)